After upgrading Swagger version, Validation is not working properly, how to fix this issue?
In my service under src/test/java I have my swagger.yaml file, Utilities.java and error.text file. In the POM file had the below dependencies and java version is 17.
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
<version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
<version>1.4.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20231013</version>
</dependency>       
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.oai/swagger-request-validator-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.oai</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-request-validator-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.38.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.21</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.21</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.21</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>


Utilities.java class:
import static com.atlassian.oai.validator.schema.SchemaValidator.ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_KEY;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.atlassian.oai.validator.report.LevelResolver;
import com.atlassian.oai.validator.report.MessageResolver;
import com.atlassian.oai.validator.report.ValidationReport;
import com.atlassian.oai.validator.report.ValidationReport.Message;
import com.atlassian.oai.validator.schema.SchemaValidator;
import io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;

public class Utilitties {

    public static boolean validation(String response, String Name, String swagPath, String errorPath) {
        try {
            boolean result = false;
            SwaggerParseResult parseResult = new OpenAPIParser().readLocation(swagPath, null, null);
            System.out.println("parseResult" + parseResult);
            OpenAPI openAPI = parseResult.getOpenAPI();

            if (openAPI == null) {
                System.err.println("Failed to load OpenAPI specification from " + swagPath);
                return false;
            }

            final SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidator(openAPI, new MessageResolver(LevelResolver.create()
                    .withLevel(ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_KEY, ValidationReport.Level.IGNORE).build()));
            Schema schema = new Schema();
            schema.set$schema(Name);
            ValidationReport rep = validator.validate(response, schema, null);

            FileWriter file;
            File f = new File(errorPath);
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
            if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                f.delete();
            }
            file = new FileWriter(errorPath);
            if (rep.hasErrors()) {
                for (Message msg : rep.getMessages()) {
                    file.write(msg.toString() + newLine);
                }
                file.close();
            } else {
                result = true;
            }

            // System.out.println("openAPI" +openAPI);
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String swagPath = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\Workspace\\org\\src\\test\\java\\orgJava\\swagger.yaml";
        String errorPath = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\Workspace\\org\\src\\test\\java\\orgJava\\error.txt";
        String response = "{\r\n" + "  \"id\": \"54321\",\r\n" + "  \"name\": \"Emily Johnson\",\r\n"
                + "  \"email\": \"emily.johnson@example.com\",\r\n" + "  \"age\": 28\r\n" + "}";
        String Name = "#/definitions/User";

        boolean abc = validation(response, Name, swagPath, errorPath);
        System.out.println("abc" + abc);
    }
}


Swagger.yaml file:
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Sample API
  description: A simple API for managing users
basePath: /api/v1
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Retrieve a list of users
      description: Returns a list of users from the system
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of users
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/User'
    post:
      summary: Create a new user
      description: Adds a new user to the system
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: user
          description: The user to be created
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: User created
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
        '400':
          description: Invalid input
  /users/{userId}:
    get:
      summary: Retrieve a specific user
      description: Returns a single user by ID
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: userId
          description: ID of the user to retrieve
          required: true
          type: string
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A user object
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
        '404':
          description: User not found
    put:
      summary: Update a specific user
      description: Updates the details of an existing user
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: userId
          description: ID of the user to update
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: user
          description: The updated user details
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: User updated
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
        '400':
          description: Invalid input
        '404':
          description: User not found
    delete:
      summary: Delete a specific user
      description: Deletes a user from the system
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: userId
          description: ID of the user to delete
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '204':
          description: User deleted
        '404':
          description: User not found
definitions:
  User:
    type: object
    required:
      - id
      - name
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        example: '12345'
      name:
        type: string
        example: 'John Doe'
      email:
        type: string
        example: 'john.doe@example.com'
      age:
        type: integer
        example: 30


In the java class by passing the API response, definition name from the swagger.yaml file we will do the validation and check the response we are getting is correct or not.
This code is working, when we used swagger-request-validator-core version as 1.5.1, which is an older version, but when we upgrade our version to 2.38.0 or the latest the some changes has been done from the code prospective I guess it is throwing compilation issues in the validate method, when we pass string and model as an input so according to the requirement we changed the code and passed the String, Schema and String values to the validate method.
But still somehow the code is not working like I have 4 scenarios, where the code needs to return false.

if you pass correct response and wrong definition name, which is not there in swagger.yaml file
if you pass wrong response or some mismatched response with the swagger.yaml file corresponding to the definition, which you passed.
if you pass both inputs as wrong.
If you pass wrong swagger File path.

Coz we are doing validation between the response and corresponding definition in swagger.yaml file.
However, the code is not working even when we pass wrong values also it is returning true.
I tried to do the code changes accordingly to fix this issue. Somehow nothing nothing got worked.
Can you help me to fix this issue.
Thanks.

Swagger Java libs v2 seem to work with OpenAPI 3.x documents only. Can you try converting your spec from the Swagger 2.0 format to OpenAPI 3.0 and use the converted file instead and see if it works? You'll probably also need to change String Name = "#/definitions/User"; to String Name = "#/components/schemas/User";.

Thanks for the information @Helen, but we have so many services like this which are consuming swagger 2.0, which is difficult task to move all to openAPI 3.0.0 and team won't accept to change, is there is any way can we achieve the requirement with swagger 2.0 by upgrading the swagger version to the latest. If yes, please let me know that.

Anyone, help me on this issue please. Thanks
